# how to handle placeholder with CardMedia in material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to handle placeholders in CardMedia material UI. when the image source is wrong, another image or placeholder has to display.

this is my code:

`

```
<CardMedia
        component="img"
        height={size}
        image={'/src/assets/icons/dLSjQE.jpg'}
        alt={`${source} cover`}
      />
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `onError` property

```
const handleImageError = (e) => {
    e.target.onerror = null; 
    e.target.src = "link to image"
}

<CardMedia
  component="img"
  height={size}
  image={'/src/assets/icons/dLSjQE.jpg'}
  alt={`${source} cover`}
   onError={handleImageError}
/>
```